# error :while loading shared libraries: libX11-xcb.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using subsystem Ubuntu under windows10.

I have already installed vscode, but when I want to open it, there was a problem.

I can't find this file, it likes not to exist.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 5):

I've got vscode running under the newer wsl2 on ubuntu, but I'm not sure if its advisable - vscode seems to be pushing you to run vscode in windows and use a wsl2 in a terminal tab.

Also vscode started the windows is a bit 'soft' i.e. fuzzy.

If you really want to give it a try then you'll need to install the dependencies.  The line below is actually the dependencies for 'xclock' which is a simpler app to test whether your X11/DISPLAY is set up

```
sudo apt install --assume-yes libx11-xcb1 libasound2 x11-apps libice6 libsm6 libxaw7 libxft2 libxmu6 libxpm4 libxt6 x11-apps xbitmaps
```

vscode certainly requires the 'libx11-xcb1 libasound2' dependencies above.

You'll also need an X11 server running e.g. you'll need to install and start:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/

There are a few gotchas - e.g. X11 security (if you are very naughty, you can disable this when starting xcxsrv) and also remember to set the

```
export DISPLAY=<your windows ip>:0
```

in wsl2 and then run your app e.g.
    xclock

I think I read somewhere that wsl2 does not yet share the same network stack so localhost in windows is not the same as localhost in wsl2 this means that 'export DISPLAY :0' doesn't work and you have to put your windows ip before :

Some further details here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZSYi8bivxA

Answer (score 0):

you need

```
sudo apt install x11-common
```

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
sudo apt install chromium-browser -y
```

Comment: OP has a problem in opening `vscode`. Please specify the reason to install `chromium-browser` and how it will solve the problem.

Comment: @SławomirSiudek Is the reason this worked for solving a problem with VS Code due to dependencies of the `chromium-browser` package that were installed along with it?