# Error while installing shared libraries libX11-xcb.so.1

Tags: xorg, dependencies, 32-bit

I'm installing a game on Ubuntu 20.04.1 x64, which is only compatible with 32x OS.
When I try to run it, the error occurs:

> error while loading shared libraries: libX11-xcb.so.1: cannot open
> shared object file: No such file or directory

I tried solution of this post [error :while loading shared libraries: libX11-xcb.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1123722/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libx11-xcb-so-1-cannot-open-shared-objec), but it didn't help.

I also installed `libx11-xcb1` and `libx11-xcb-dev` packages.

The output of `ldd game_launcher | grep not` is `libX11-xcb1.so.1 => not found`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1271894/edit) your question and add output of `ldd game-executable | grep not` (change *game-executable* to actual file-name) to it. You may need more than one library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get 32-bit version of [the library](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=i386&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libX11-xcb.so.1) you have to add `:i386` after the package name:

```
sudo apt-get install libx11-xcb1:i386
```